# How to run/execute Selenium tests via CI (e.g., Jenkins)

Tags: ant, selenium, playframework, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I've started using Play! for an application which we are migrating from Wicket in my organization.
 As per our policy, we need to keep all tests up and running via Jenkins and I was able to antify the application and configured Jenkins to call Ant target 'auto-test' successfully. 
But it seems like the selenium tests are getting left out.
Is there any way to include/call them from Ant?

Would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with selenium, but I know it is possible with Jenkins with some configuration, I think you may find these links helpful

1. Jenkins Selenium Plugin [[1](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Selenium+Plugin)]
2. Closer to what you need to be doing [[2](http://blog.infostretch.com/?p=328)]

If you have anymore questions please feel free to ask.

Goodluck!

Answer (score 0):

Just for a reference, 'auto-test' targets runs the selenium tests as well.

It seems I overlooked the selenium test packs as we have number of suites (app, functional, daos etc...), its my bad.